# Is there any way to know if a magento is community or enterprise without accesing the code?

Tags: magento-enterprise, version

I know I can check what version of magento is installed using

something like this: http://magentoversion.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tailoy.com.pe%2F

And I know that there is almost no difference between the enterprise and the community,

but I would like to know if some of the biggest websites using Magento on some countries are paying the fee.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if EE version or CE by code](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30358/check-if-ee-version-or-ce-by-code)

Comment: @Teja bhagavan Kollepara , why put random  duplicate vote?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara it's a total different question, why did you say it's duplicate?

Comment: @Saikios, based on my understanding those two are same, thats y i said duplicate. if i am wrong, the moderator will not approve right?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara so for you NOT accessing the code means how can I DO ACCESS the code and check? because your answer is only on how to do it with access through an ftp and adding code.

Comment: https://magescan.com/ it is provide more detail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can detect if a website is running Magento Enterprise Edition by hitting *website_base_url*/giftcard/customer in your browser. If you get a 404 Page Not Found error then that means they are NOT running MEE (Magento Enterprise Edition). If you get redirected to a login page that means they ARE most likely running MEE.

For more [info](https://jayelkaake.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/check-if-a-website-is-running-magento-community-or-enterprise-edition/)

Comment: Side note: if the GiftCard module has been disabled on an Enterprise edition, I'm pretty sure this test won't work.

Comment: @ Raphael  yes agree, is there any alternate to have the details.

Comment: Check @tejas's answer

Answer (score 15):

Check for URL `base_website_URL/magento_version` for Magento version

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: +1 but if module `Magento_Version` is disabled or they have redirection for this URL then it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

-- > You can easily check if a website is running Magento Enterprise Edition or Magento Community Edition hitting

just simply write --> **website_base_url/magento_version**

--> after you will see **top of the left corner** some thing like... (Magento/2.2 (Community) or Magetno/2.3(Community), or Magento/2.3/(Enterprise) version...

> **@*****Check Magento version using cmd line*****@**

### _______________________________________________________

**(Note : This cmd only for magento 1)**

simply type -->   **php -r "require 'app/Mage.php'; echo Mage::getVersion(); "**