# Magento verion is community or enterprise

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm working with few Magento websites and how can i find out that which website is enterprise and which one is community.

Comment: You may find the answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134634/is-there-any-way-to-know-if-a-magento-is-community-or-enterprise-without-accesin/134637#134637

Comment: @krishnaati95Dev I'm sorry but i'm not too familiar with magento. Can you explain me how can i use this method.

Comment: @ Sandro website_base_url/giftcard/customer in your browser, If you get a 404 Page that means they are NOT running magento enterprise.). If you get redirected to a login page that means they ARE most likely running MEE.

Comment: @krishnaati95Dev yes i have tried but i'm not sure because :
 
Side note: if the GiftCard module has been disabled on an Enterprise edition, I'm pretty sure this test won't work. – Raphael at Digital Pianism

Comment: @Sandro yes agree, there is no alternate,  unless to  contact site owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a directory `app/code/core/Enterprise`, it is Enterprise Edition.

Comment: if you're really unlucky it could be the long dead Professional Edition.